# Configure Elasticsearch in JHipster with URL

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I want to use cloud elasticsearch (Bonsai) with JHipster. 
Bonsai provides BONSAI_URL env variable. 
How is this properly configured in application-prod.yml?

Comment: I added answer with example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623238/setting-up-bonsai-elasticsearch-in-jhipster-heroku